# why jsp page doesn't reload when tomee is in debugger mode

Tags: java, jsp, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am running Tomee and its integrated in IntelliJ and i have the run configuration set to hot deployment(auto-reloading).  When i run Tomee in debugger mode in IntelliJ and save any changes to the JSP page, and try to reload the JSP page in web browser(chrome for instance), it doesn't reload the page, just gets stuck in the reloading phase.

when tomee is not in debugging mode, the page reloads just fine in browser, but when tomee is in debugging mode, the page won't reload, why is that?

please see image below:

[image]

the page gets stuck in the reloading phase...

Comment: have you checked all breakpoints are removed ? It might be so that you have put any breakpoint in your code (in flow). Please Remove all of your breakpoints first..

Comment: try this https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-disabling-and-removing-breakpoints.html

Comment: @VikrantKashyap i removed the break points and still did not work, but question, if there are no break points, whats the point of debugging?

Comment: @VikrantKashyap ok ur correct, i removed all break points, and it reloads just fine.  But whats the piont of debugging without any break points?

Comment: @VikrantKashyap actually i take that back, i removed all break pionts again and page still did not reload.

Comment: Sometimes any breakpoint will not enables you to redirect to the webpage.. It will stuck to that point. I was thinking problem with breakpoint actually